# FFMPEG - Concatenate 2 MP4 Files, one has video and audio and the other has only audio

Tags: shell, audio, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to merge 2 mp4 files using FFMPEG. One of these files has both video and audio (`track1.mp4`), while the other one has only audio (`track2.mp4`). The names of these files are listed in a text file called `'filesToMerge.txt'` in the following manner:

```
file 'track1.mp4'
file 'track2.mp4'
```

I then execute the following ffmpeg command to merge them.

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i filesToMerge.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

However, the concatenated file that is generated consists of only the first file that is  listed in `filesToMerge.txt`. That is, if `track1.mp4` (which has both video and audio) is the first file in the list, then only that file makes up output.mp4 (the concatenated file produced) and vice versa.

I would like for both files to be in `output.mp4`. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 (if that helps). How can I solve this problem?

When I run this command
    `ffmpeg -i track1.mp4 -i track2.mp4 output.mp4`
I get the following

```
ffmpeg version N-76944-g15206ff Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
      built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)
      configuration: --extra-libs=-ldl --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --enable-avresample --disable-debug --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=amrwb --enable-libpulse --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-avisynth --enable-libsoxr --enable-libxvid --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvidstab
      libavutil      55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
      libavcodec     57. 16.101 / 57. 16.101
      libavformat    57. 19.100 / 57. 19.100
      libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
      libavfilter     6. 17.100 /  6. 17.100
      libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
      libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
      libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
      libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
    Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'track1.mp4':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : isom
        minor_version   : 512
        compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
        encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
      Duration: 00:00:10.76, start: 0.023220, bitrate: 351 kb/s
        Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 800x400 [SAR 400:533 DAR 800:533], 181 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
        Metadata:
          handler_name    : VideoHandler
        Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 194 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'track2.mp4':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : isom
        minor_version   : 512
        compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
        creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
        encoder         : Lavf52.32.0
      Duration: 00:00:32.21, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 46 kb/s
        Stream #1:0(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 43 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
          handler_name    : SoundHandler
    [libx264 @ 0x3950ce0] using SAR=400/533
    [libx264 @ 0x3950ce0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA3 LZCNT BMI2
    [libx264 @ 0x3950ce0] profile High, level 3.0
    [libx264 @ 0x3950ce0] 264 - core 142 r2491 24e4fed - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=1 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
    Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : isom
        minor_version   : 512
        compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
        encoder         : Lavf57.19.100
        Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 800x400 [SAR 400:533 DAR 800:533], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
        Metadata:
          handler_name    : VideoHandler
          encoder         : Lavc57.16.101 libx264
        Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (libfdk_aac) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          handler_name    : SoundHandler
          encoder         : Lavc57.16.101 libfdk_aac
    Stream mapping:
      Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
      Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (libfdk_aac))
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
    frame=  270 fps= 99 q=28.0 Lsize=     382kB time=00:00:10.72 bitrate= 291.9kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    
    video:230kB audio:143kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 2.482656%
    [libx264 @ 0x3950ce0] frame I:2     Avg QP:18.87  size:109452
    [libx264 @ 0x3950ce0] frame P:68    Avg QP:15.09  size:   171
    [libx264 @ 0x3950ce0] frame B:200   Avg QP:23.33  size:    23
    [libx264 @ 0x3950ce0] consecutive B-frames:  1.1%  0.0%  1.1% 97.8%
    [libx264 @ 0x3950ce0] mb I  I16..4: 11.0% 39.6% 49.5%
    [libx264 @ 0x3950ce0] mb P  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  5.9%  0.1%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:93.9%
    [libx264 @ 0x3950ce0] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  0.3%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:99.7%  L0:21.8% L1:78.2% BI: 0.0%
    [libx264 @ 0x3950ce0] 8x8 transform intra:39.7% inter:92.8%
    [libx264 @ 0x3950ce0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 92.0% 95.0% 73.2% inter: 0.1% 1.4% 0.0%
    [libx264 @ 0x3950ce0] i16 v,h,dc,p:  1% 30%  4% 66%
    [libx264 @ 0x3950ce0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu:  6% 55% 16%  2%  4%  2%  8%  2%  6%
    [libx264 @ 0x3950ce0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 17% 18% 13%  7%  9%  7% 12%  6% 11%
    [libx264 @ 0x3950ce0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 44% 35% 10% 11%
    [libx264 @ 0x3950ce0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
    [libx264 @ 0x3950ce0] ref P L0: 98.1%  0.2%  1.1%  0.5%
    [libx264 @ 0x3950ce0] ref B L0: 85.1% 13.2%  1.7%
    [libx264 @ 0x3950ce0] ref B L1: 93.6%  6.4%
    [libx264 @ 0x3950ce0] kb/s:174.10
```

Answer (score 1):

So if I'm understanding correctly, you want the final outputted video file to play track1.mp4, which will have video and audio, and then track2.mp4, which will have only audio and display nothing? The following answer assumes this is your desired output.

I tried several solutions, namely splitting the audio from the video and concatenating the audios first, then remerging, and generating a black video to go with the track2.mp4. I couldn't convince either to work. The final solution I found that DID work well is a bash [script](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#extscript) on the ffmpeg wiki's [Concatenate](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate) page.

The steps are very straightforward. Copy the bash script into a file named "mmcat" in the same directory as track1/2.mp4. Then run

```
chmod +x mmcat && ./mmcat track1.mp4 track2.mp4 final.mp4
```

You should now have your desired file in final.mp4.

Note that this method does involve some transcoding, so you will theoretically lose some quality in doing so. Based on my experimentations, I don't believe this is avoidable since stream copying is only supported if the codecs exactly match, and you don't appear to be in that situation (your audio files have different bitrates, sample rates, etc).

Also note that whatever is in the final frame of video from track1 will be displayed, frozen, for the duration of track2. If you want it to go to black, you'd better make sure your final frame in track1 is a black frame. Doing so has been left as an exercise for OP.

Comment: First, thanks for resurrecting my post. I followed your advice and got the following error- " /tmp/mcs_v_all: Operation not permitted." I then turned on the logging and found the following errors in the log files: "Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid data found when processing input" AND "Output file #0 does not contain any stream"

Comment: I'm not certain about the errors in the logfile. They could be normal for the script, as I at least know it tries several methods. The first error appears to be caused by you not having access to /tmp. Find the line in the script that reads "TMP=/tmp" and change /tmp to a directory to which you have access. Alternatively, if you have root access, try "sudo chmod 777 /tmp".

Comment: Ipreams, I was able to create a merged video using "ffmpeg -i track1.mp4 -i track2.mp4 output.mp4" However, track2 which has audio only, becomes the background music for track1. Hence, it seems that both are playing simultaneously. Do you have an idea for a fix?

Comment: Yes, you're not concatenating at all. Instead, you're creating a file with a video track and two audio tracks. You need to look into ffmpeg concatenation (I linked to [the relevant ffmpeg wiki page](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate) in my answer) and/or [the mmcat script](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#extscript) (also linked above).